# change Microsoft SQL Server (SqlClient) Datasource to ODBC Datasource

Tags: vb.net, datasource

I use vb.net and windows form and sqlserver

I added Data Source(Microsoft SQL Server (SqlClient)) to my project. and now I need to change it to  ODBC Data Source .

How Can I do That?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

See these resources - you cannot simply change your `SqlClient/SqlCOnnection` - you need to use `OdbcConnection` instead:

- [Connecting to an ODBC Data Source Using ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719762%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)
- [ADO.NET ODBC connection in VB.NET](http://vb.net-informations.com/ado.net-dataproviders/ado.net-odbcconnection.htm)

ODBC is a technology several generations older than ADO.NET/SqlClient - why do you want to "downgrade" back into the dark ages?? What are you trying to achieve that you cannot do using SqlClient?? If you really must connect to a multitude of different datasources, I would strongly recommend using / investigating OleDB instead of ODBC. ODBC is really quite old, and e.g. doesn't have any 64-bit capable drivers.... OleDB does!

See the [Wikipedia article on OleDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLE_DB), and view impressive lists of OleDB data providers [here](http://www.carlprothman.net/Default.aspx?tabid=87) and [here](http://www.sqlsummit.com/oledbVen.htm) for some insights.

Comment: thanls for your reply. I want to set my datasource connection string dinamically. so I decide to use odbc.

Comment: @mahsa: what kind of data sources do you want to connect to?? A **lot** of them have native OleDB providers - that would be a much better, much more modern approach than ODBC....

Comment: I wrote My project, its complete . And now I need to change it. I used Datasource which is in visual studio menu => Data => Add new datasource.

Comment: @Mahsa: you could **also** write your code to use just the `IDbConnection` and `IDbCommand` interfaces from the `System.Data` namespace, and then decide at runtime which concrete class (SqlConnection, OracleConnection, OleDbConnection etc.) you'd want to use. This would give you some degree of independance from an actual database, yet you'd be using the familiar ADO.NET data providers - instead of an old, clunky technology like ODBC.....

Comment: yes I use that method (Interface) in my new projects. but in this case . the project is too old. and I just want to be able to change connection string dinamically